# Paypal environment variables credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

How can i set environment variables for PayPal credentials ?
I searched a lot but didn't got any clue.
This is the code in 
paypal.rb

```
PayPal::SDK.load("config/paypal.yml", Rails.env)
PayPal::SDK.logger = Rails.logger
merchant_id = "sts9n"
public_key = "3jnfbc24f76"
private_key = "a0167fd52cf3857e"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your credentials to credentials.yml as follows

```
EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit
```

Add PayPal keys as follows in the credentials file

```
paypal: 
 development:
  client_id: "sdsdsdvsdvsv"
  client_secret: "sdfsdsdv"
 production:
  client_id: 'sdsdsdvsdvsv'
  client_secret: 'sdsdsdvsdvsv'
```

Then create a YML file in your config file called paypal.yml

```
development:
  client_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.paypal[:development][:client_id] %>
  client_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.paypal[:development][:client_secret] %>

production:
  client_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.paypal[:production][:client_id] %>
  client_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.paypal[:production][:client_secret] %>
  mode: live
```

Then create a paypal.rb file in initializers folder

```
paypal_config_file = File.join(Rails.root,'config','paypal.yml')
raise "#{paypal_config_file} is missing!" unless File.exists? paypal_config_file
paypal_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('config','paypal.yml'))).result)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys

CLIENT_ID = paypal_config[:client_id]
CLIENT_SECRET = paypal_config[:client_secret]
```

In this way, you don't need to change any code when switching to development to production.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add your keys to rails credentials:

`EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit`

```
production:
  paypal:
     client_id: 'qwertzuiop'
     client_secret: 'poiuztrewq'
```

then use this credentials in `config/paypal.yml`:

```
[…]
production:
  mode: live
  client_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, paypal, :client_id) %>
  client_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, paypal, :client_secret) %>
```

Or you can add your environment variables in your environment config file. For instance, in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, paypal, :client_id)
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, paypal, :client_secret)
```

And in `config/paypal.yml`

```
[…]
production:
  mode: live
  client_id: PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret: PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET
```